# what is a polynomial having a real quadratic factor with complex conjugate roots mean?

Tags: polynomials

Can someone tell me how to create a quartic equation with quadratic factors with complex conjugate roots. In a question i am asked to create a polynomial having a real quadratic factor with complex conjugate roots.

Answer (score 1):

Choose your favorite complex non-conjugate numbers, which are $\;i, 2i\;$ , and then

$$(x-i)(x+i)(x-2i)(x+2i)=(x^2+1)(x^2+4)=x^4+5x^2+4$$

Comment: i just graphed the equation u gave as example and noticed the graph has no inflection points and only one turning point. i thought all polynomial of degree four have 2 inflection points and 3 turning points?

Comment: Inflextion points are extreme points of the first derivative, which in this case is a cubic polynomial: why would a cubic have to have two extreme points?! For example, its derivative could be a quadratic without roots, or with a single couble one...I never heard that thing you're asking about quartics.